# PHP Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ivoa27.so' [Netsuite]

Tags: php, nginx, dependencies, odbc, netsuite

I am trying to connect netsuite ODBC driver with php on Linux.
It works fine on Linux but with nginx, the php connection fails.

I seems to have a problem of dependencies that I can't figure out.

ldd ivoa.so.27 works perfectly on the server linux but ldd ivoa.so.27 when using the user www-data can't find two files.

See below.

> ldd /opt/calnexsol/engagement_form/odbc_driver/lib64/ivoa27.so

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc72b54000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007ff74b42b000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ff74b227000)
    libicuuc.so.42 => /opt/calnexsol/engagement_form/odbc_driver/lib64/libicuuc.so.42 (0x00007ff74afcd000)
    libicudata.so.42 => /opt/calnexsol/engagement_form/odbc_driver/lib64/libicudata.so.42 (0x00007ff749f88000)
    libpam.so.0 => /lib64/libpam.so.0 (0x00007ff749d79000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ff749b5d000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007ff749855000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007ff749553000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007ff74933d000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff748f6f000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff74b9de000)
    libaudit.so.1 => /lib64/libaudit.so.1 (0x00007ff748d46000)
    libcap-ng.so.0 => /lib64/libcap-ng.so.0 (0x00007ff748b40000)
```

> sudo runuser -u www-data -- ldd /opt/calnexsol/engagement_form/odbc_driver/lib64/ivoa27.so

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffc093c000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007fb274424000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fb274220000)
    libicuuc.so.42 => not found
    libicudata.so.42 => not found
    libpam.so.0 => /lib64/libpam.so.0 (0x00007fb274011000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fb273df5000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fb273aed000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fb2737eb000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fb2735d5000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fb273207000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fb2749d7000)
    libaudit.so.1 => /lib64/libaudit.so.1 (0x00007fb272fde000)
    libcap-ng.so.0 => /lib64/libcap-ng.so.0 (0x00007fb272dd8000)
```

Please advise. If anyone have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have set `OASDK_ODBC_HOME`, you can add `/opt/calnexsol/engagement_form/odbc_driver/lib64` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.  e.g.,

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/calnexsol/engagement_form/odbc_driver/lib64
```